# How to align test answer choices so as to preserve space (not all vertical)?

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment

Does anyone know how to align the choices like that?

[image: as in the image]

I only can do it one under the other but I would like to utilize the space better as the image above. I also don't want to press space until the second option is at the place I want. I want all of them to be in "numbering" format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with 6 cells, as 2 wide, 3 long, then merge the bottom two cells into one row with center alignment.

Then use the border drawing tool to make them white/invisible and type your choices in them.

Comment: For more, see Word MVP Shauna Kelly's writing on using Tables: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/4UseTablesTabs.htm